# string before dynamic text regexp, return repetitive array result

Tags: regex, actionscript

I'm trying to get some string before '_', I managed to do that using regexp and make it dynamically, but somehow it returns in array form with 2 repeat answer.
I know I could just get like array[0] and pass it over, but it doesn't looks straightforward. What have I done wrong?

```
function stringBefore($string:String, $before:String):void {
        var s:String = $string;         
        var start:RegExp = /^([^/;
        var end:RegExp = /]*)/g;
        var completeRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(start.source + $before + end.source);

        trace(s.match(completeRegExp))
    }
```

Exp: Passing something like 'SFX_SOUND' I will get [SFX, SFX] in an array

Comment: Hmm strange I tested new RegExp('^([^_]*)') and it gave me just SFX once.

Comment: Using your's give me 2 result as well. var reg:RegExp =  new RegExp(/^([^_]*)/g); returns 1. Not dynamic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine regexes that way. You can only combine string patterns and then compile a regex object. So, you might want to fix your code like this:

```
var start:RegExp = "^([^";
var end:RegExp = "]*)";
var completeRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(start.source + $before + end.source, "g");
```

Or, maybe just using strings

```
var start:String = "^([^";
var end:String = "]*)";
var completeRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(start + $before + end, "g");
```

Comment: this works. so if using regexp, the result will always be in array form?

Comment: `.match` returns an array (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match()). If you are looking for the 1st string value, you can access the first match by using an index `[0]`, and there is no need adding `"g"` option (so that we do not search the whole string).